# Split a storm stream equally between several database writer bolts / database query routers?

Tags: java, apache-storm

Having a storm cluster that connects to a MongoDB cluster with n query routers, would it be sensible to create a "SplitStreamBolt" that splits the stream equally to n streams and connect to each of those streams a writer bolt with a specific query router attached?

How would such a SplitStreamBolt be defined? Is there any better method to split a stream in that way?

Basic try:

```
public static class SplitStreamBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    private OutputCollector _collector;

    private int cycleStream = 1;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        if(cycleStream == 1)
        {
            _collector.emit("mongoStream1", input, new Values(1));
            cycleStream = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            _collector.emit("mongoStream2", input, new Values(2));
            cycleStream = 1;
        };
        _collector.ack(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(final OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("mongoStream1", new Fields("stream"));
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declareStream("mongoStream2", new Fields("stream"));
    }
}
```

Do I have to declare new fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the "shuffle grouping" is sufficient to partition the tuples among the MongoDB writers. In fact although the tuples are randomly emitted the documentation said :

> Shuffle grouping: Tuples are randomly distributed across the bolt's
>   tasks in a way such that **each bolt is guaranteed to get an equal
>   number of tuples**.

Comment: Well, currently i have different bolts (same class, different conf) for each query router, so if Id just use shufflegrouping, each tuple would be processed twice wouldnt it?